# Python attrs library and referencing instance methods

Tags: python, attr, python-attrs

How can I convert the class below to use the [attrs library](https://attrs.readthedocs.io/en):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, api, template=None, **kwargs):
        self.api = api
        self.param1 = param1
        if template is not None:
            self.template = api.get_template(desc=template)
```

Specifically, how do I deal with the dependency of one parameter on the initialization of another?  In my initial attempt, I started with a class like this:

```
@attr.s
class MyAttrClass(object):
    api = attr.ib()
    param1 = attr.ib()
```

But I am unsure of how to deal with the `template` attribute?  My initial thought was to do:

```
def __attrs_post_init__(self):
    self.template = api.get_template(desc=template)
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this, though?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [`takes_self` argument to `Factory`](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.Factory) may be useful to you.

One problem I think I see here is that you are taking an argument called template with looks like it's a different kind of thing (perhaps a `str`) than what you set as `self.template` (perhaps a `Template`).  I suggest you give those different names, and then do something like this:

```
from attr import Factory, attrib, attrs
from attr.validators import instance_of

from my.code import API, Template

@attrs
class Foo(object):
    api = attrib(validator=instance_of(API))

    _template_name = attrib(validator=instance_of(str))

    template = attrib(
        validator=instance_of(Template),
        default=Factory(
            lambda self: self.api.get_template(self._template_name)
        ),
        takes_self=True,
        init=False,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

'param1' from your question is hard to follow, and I can only assume it is to come from 'kwargs'?

```
@attr.s
class MyAttrClass(object):
    api = attr.ib()
    template = attr.ib(default=None)
    param1 = attr.ib()

    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        if self.template is not None:
            self.template = api.get_template(desc=template)
```

should be a workable solution to deal with the template attribute, but what i am yet to resolve is how to deal with the kwargs.  I am looking into that myself, so will post a solution once i discover one.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for dealing with the kwargs in attr.s?